# Is there a way to make these generic functions work in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to use generics to type the following `setValue` and `getValue` functions correctly? I understand the error since it sees multiple types for the properties given. But is there a way to also make the functions aware of the name/age property type based on property value provided?

```
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

interface Person {
    age: BehaviorSubject<number>;
    name: BehaviorSubject<string>;
}

class SomeClass {
    private _somePerson:Person = {
        age: new BehaviorSubject(0),
        name: new BehaviorSubject('John')
    };

    public setValue<T>(inID: number, inProperty: keyof(Person), inValue: T): void {
        this._somePerson[inProperty].next(inValue);
    }

    public getValue<T>(inID: number, inProperty: keyof(Person)): Observable<T> {
        return this._somePerson[inProperty].asObservable();
    }

}
```

[TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgIQKYAsCGA3Y0DKArgEYBWqAxjADRwDyxAzqlNpsQDapwC+cAZlAgg4AcigAPUo1EBuALAAoJcAB2MFv0wVuABRaMIqxErhm4mAOaoAXCgw48UImUowAPKsIhiLAHwKiuZwqpggtvZYuAQk5FTujDBQapYBSjxKShQcmIyMcPjCqADCOXkmQeZgyWwacAD6huH6UIaqNi1tcAC8FcHBVhGqqADukY4xrlQAFAAMAJTUpv1moeF2w2NoUU4ucTDTogBSEOiqovPLZjyBV3BgJBzAFHDMMABqmByEqO4AKn5pmoAJIAEQ23l8UFoal0QjALBgAE87ABrVBIiD8aadIyLOBqT7fCJ-eZ2bAQYAAEz6KzgMHQwEYADpGkVcaoANqw+GIpEAXWZwwkB0JXx+80CwQyykqZgenGecGsH3FvwBQNUYIhPhYMNUcIgCNgKLg6Mx2I58zJ9CYLDYnHVflpKygqBghCgxgZTNZTVQHO5Bt5JsFuQYzFY7C400ldxl6SUQA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NDDp1N) meet your needs? If so I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes! That works great - I would never had thought to go that route and was trying to user infer in all kinds of crazy ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually you want to express the operations as [indexing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) key `K` (corresponding to `inProperty`) into some "base" `Person` type where the values are just `string` and `number` and not `BehaviorSubject<string>` and `BehaviorSubject<number>`.  You could define `BasePerson` like

```
type BasePerson = {
    [K in keyof Person]: Person[K] extends BehaviorSubject<infer V> ? V : never
}
```

using [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to turn `BehaviorSubject<V>` into `V`, equivalent to this:

```
/* type BasePerson = {
  age: number;
  name: string;
}*/
```

And then the class would look like:

```
class SomeClass {
    private _somePerson: Person = {
        age: new BehaviorSubject(0),
        name: new BehaviorSubject('John')
    };

    public setValue<K extends keyof Person>(
        inID: number, inProperty: K, inValue: BasePerson[K]
    ): void {
        this._somePerson[inProperty].next(inValue); // error!
    }

    public getValue<K extends keyof Person>(
        inID: number, inProperty: K
    ): Observable<BasePerson[K]> {
        return this._somePerson[inProperty].asObservable(); // error!
    }
}
```

And that all works for the consumer of the class:

```
const sc = new SomeClass();
sc.setValue(123, "age", "oops"); // error
sc.setValue(123, "age", 123); // okay
sc.setValue(123, "name", 123); // error
sc.setValue(123, "name", "okay"); // okay
const obsNum = sc.getValue(123, "age"); 
// const obsNum: Observable<number>
const obsStr = sc.getValue(123, "name");
// const obsStr: Observable<string>
```

But, as you can see, the compiler is unable to follow the logic inside the implementations of `setValue()` and `getValue()`.  In order to do so, it would need to see that `BehaviorSubject<Person[K] extends BehaviorSubject<infer V> ? V : never>` is the same type as `Person[K]` for *generic* `K`.  This is unfortunately beyond the current capabilities of the compiler. It loses track of the *correlation* between `BasePerson[K]` and `Person[K]`.

And so you get errors saying that what you're doing might not be safe.  This is essentially the problem described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) (that issue talks about correlated [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) instead of generic types, but it's the same underlying problem).

---

If you don't care about having the compiler verify type safety in those implementations, you could just use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress the warnings:

```
public setValue<K extends keyof Person>(
    inID: number, inProperty: K, inValue: BasePerson[K]
): void {
    this._somePerson[inProperty].next(inValue as never); // okay
}

public getValue<K extends keyof Person>(
    inID: number, inProperty: K
): Observable<BasePerson[K]> {
    return this._somePerson[inProperty].asObservable() as any; // okay
}
```

That compiles with no error, but only because type assertions are shifting the burden of verifying type safety from the compiler to the developer.

---

If you *do* care about the compiler verifying type safety of those implementations, then you'll need to refactor as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  Instead of defining `Person` and computing `BasePerson` from it, you can define `BasePerson` direcly:

```
interface BasePerson {
    age: number;
    name: string;
}
```

And then `Person` can be expressed as a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over its properties:

```
type Person = { [K in keyof BasePerson]:
    BehaviorSubject<BasePerson[K]>
}
```

This representation is very important, because now operations on `Person[K]` will stay generic.  That is, the compiler can follow the correlation when indexing into a mapped type:

```
class SomeClass {
    private _somePerson: Person = {
        age: new BehaviorSubject(0),
        name: new BehaviorSubject('John')
    };

    public setValue<K extends keyof BasePerson>(
        inID: number, inProperty: K, inValue: BasePerson[K]
    ): void {
        this._somePerson[inProperty].next(inValue); // okay
    }

    public getValue<K extends keyof BasePerson>(
        inID: number, inProperty: K
    ): Observable<BasePerson[K]> {
        return this._somePerson[inProperty].asObservable(); // okay
    }
}
```

The compiler sees that `this._somePerson[inProperty]` is of type `Person[K]`, which evaluates to `BehaviorSubject<BasePerson[K]>`, after which everything else just works.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgIQKYAsCGA3Y0DKArgEYBWqAxjADRwDyxAzqlNpsQDapwC+cAZlAgg4AcigAPUo1EBuALAAoJQDtMIVIzCYK3OlGABzREqVxzcYCpgt+O7gAUWjCCpOKLnuJkOoAXCgYOHhQRGSUMAA8KoQgxCwAfAoeXuZqGgFoWLgEJORUkYwwBiqGSWYWPKYp5jAAnmDcyJjMTlAubgC87qnmANoA0pZuANaodRD8cG0dALp+FakzroOzcKgSNioAJoyB2SFh+VFW-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-tB2HN46IY38mJFNjOLgHjfD4uA5JEgcIBGTA6gk+jGMXFiOO4+FlNU3tRPQ6AdKkhdU1kwyFOM-jNLqYSzPU5y8II+AICYAA5WJWSIyt5xkuTuN4ntPgHfCVEInzGH8kBbyYeDH0dKFwwSTzYu8ph8GKQLJJC-S7PkrjjMijlRJiuK8uKZL7wQp9ESsMolFwyd4S0ew4AAQRJJt3DeKwbCgOxdG3dpXBLMFfEyIIcmVYUogyxIaK8OUBUWo4IkKYpWvKDkOs8P4mkBFk2WNQZhndcYt2BeZjTrbMV1dPZFW2lUClOc4rlue4eReKAcM+H5ToBDMppBT9ZohVaoHWtJ1ARfbSnWng0QxCwsRxOByMJYlSWNSlgGpbhQNfKHmR3QKYa-blIT5LbDi+mBxSlfckYyRmFQWlnlrVTVtV1ccjSw8xTU4Wc9NTZcXTXN1Ny9Hc93FrxD1DaEI2Gc9L3jOBE2GJjMnOt9sxvOACyLGbOSAitqwZSmOnrFRdagls2zZzt9O8PYniBtS4A0rTxyx1JJfNS1itl51V3XW7PUmjpVa-cwNePLWz0bONrzVvN6BSh9EOfU2offG3eh-P8AN+YCHdrcDXez5tK1gwumqQiVfe8FQ6jcoOPLVidPGO7GvKIwLSLx-FKJJairJlh1SvCpT+ME1zULEyyOUkxeDLK3jaFMzfg+0nfdOkkqwoc5GTI4wOLOB8-rNC+zytvpytI30TT+y2qEoCt0Iql9bLX0UqgVyUU4A1VygApKBdGppWiCeKAWUOQwKDnVKAhV6LRyXmAiq61qrj3ivlKADVUrFxaqUNBHUuraAmgAdWgCMImk5hrWFsD1F8LI6aw01uGRGFhNrUORCDScJ0GiOBpmyOA10rAJy3Dwncj01YfX5scEukNnbZjQSPMO0DCbTwokYvhFIqSYBpBTJkSdpqXTVp4BmU91FCmOOzaUDjhHI3lMzVxqoNRah1HqIeYtOQR2liApcsc3qKKmMoqGKdU7p3hlnSCOcDZJmNhDJ2WYcx53zIWYsZjeh2xAo7OsEE9YexdB2ZM+lKqclHuHGcUdImOmiQrDcd04ml2Tr6TxacVDBgEaeHWzd9YDAtnBIuT54k6NmB+TmcAq7-kAnXaxjc3ZxhgowaZHd55D3Ee1IAA)

Comment: Thanks for the help and your excellent write up for the answer. I am trying to maintain type safety in the logic. The details here really helped me see the issue and understand your solution - thanks for taking the time!